# WebAPI as a front end for Orleans Service does not receive requests

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, orleans

I am trying to make a WebAPI front end for Orleans service, but my WebAPI does not receive any requests

I following the tutorial as described at https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Tutorials/Front-Ends-for-Orleans-Services.html.

Also tried to run Orleans GPSTracker sample, but I have the same issue.

I'm using Orleans version 1.3.0 on VisualStudio 2015 4.5.2, and got the same results using Orleans 1.3.1.

If I use console application as an orleans client it works Ok.

recently I tried VisualStudio2017RC 4.6.2 and my WebApi client works.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Did you checked your firewall settings or access rights?

Comment: What does "the web api stacks" mean?

Comment: @Gigi stacks means that service not responds for web requests

Comment: @Kalpesh Chheda what exactly should i check?

Comment: Try to run visual studio as administrator, turn off firewall.